# Angular 4. Troubles with Forms Module

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-form

I took example from here: [Angular 4 Forms Directive (ngForm)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgForm-directive.html) 
And get errors:
no directives for ngModel and ngForm. Seems directive wasn't included.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "NgForm" ("<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" [ERROR ->]#f="NgForm" novalidate> <input name="first" [(ngModel)]="first" required #first="ngModel"> .....

core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
   <input name="first" ngModel required [ERROR ->]#first="ngModel">
   <input name="last" ngModel>
   <button>Submit</button>"): ng:///AuthModule/LoginComponent.html@2:44 Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate><input name="first" ngModel required [ERROR ->]#first="ngModel"><input name="last" ngModel><button>Submit</button>"): ng:///AuthModule/LoginComponent.html@2:44
at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:50027:34) [angular]....
```

Files are here:

Module file: login.module.ts

```
     import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
     import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
     import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
     import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

     import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
     @NgModule({
         imports: [
             CommonModule,
             FormsModule,
             BrowserModule
         ],
         declarations: [LoginComponent],
         bootstrap: [LoginComponent],
    })
    export class LoginModule {}
```

Component file: login.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
        selector: 'sc-auth-login',
        template: `
            <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
            <input name="first" ngModel required #first="ngModel">
            <input name="last" ngModel>
            <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
            <p>First name value: {{ first.value }}</p>
            <p>First name valid: {{ first.valid }}</p>
            <p>Form value: {{ f.value | json }}</p>
            <p>Form valid: {{ f.valid }}</p>
        `,
    })
    export class LoginComponent {
        onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
        console.log(f.value);  // { first: '', last: '' }
        console.log(f.valid);  // false
    }
}
```

Any idea what is wrong with it?

Comment: So.. solution is including FormsModule in first parent module not globally.
My project structure: app => auth => login.
Forms was included in app.module not in auth.module.
After I added it to auth, it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide name to ngModel.so that local variable can be created.

```
<input name="first" [(ngModel)]="first" required #first="ngModel">
<input name="last" [(ngModel)]="last" #last="ngModel">
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was just missing **ngModel** directive to the input field

```
<input ngModel name="name" #name="ngModel">
```

by adding it resolved the issue.